# Create Single Entity on Doctrine 2 + Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

i'm trying to generate a single entity from my database using symfony2 but i need a way to target one table to generate the YML file :

i have tried this

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle yml

but it does not i got all yml from all table in my doctrine folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle:YOURENTITYNAME yml

Comment: you need to add path option to spécifiy the folder ,

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle:YOURENTITYNAME yml --path=src